# Would An Earth-Like Moon Be Tidally Locked?

Tags: earth-like, moons, orbital-mechanics, gas-giants, tides

Could a moon of similar size to the Earth orbiting a gas giant be tidally locked compared to its host planet? What effect would that have on the moon, especially the biosphere?

Comment: Tidal locking of a moon still results in a day/night cycle on the moon. Your main problem will be having a quick enough orbital period without being inside the Roche limit. But, Io for instance has a sidereal 'day' length of 1.7 Earth days while still being tidally locked.

Comment: "*Could a moon of similar size to the Earth orbiting a gas giant be tidally locked*" Sure, at the right distance.  "*What effect would that have on the planet?*"  Since the Moon is so tiny compared to gas giants... not much.

Comment: I meant the moon, typo.

Comment: There are a large number of questions about tidally locked moons. I'm sure there's more than one that this question is effectively a duplicate of.

Answer (score 2):

First Question:Yes, as Samuel and RonJon points out, Io is a moon orbiting a gas giant that is tidally locked to a gas giant Jupiter.

Second Question: As for the effects to the moon that is tidally locked (like Io is to Jupiter). As far as I can tell, **heat**! Neil Degrasse Tyson [wrote a piece about Tidal Forces](http://www.haydenplanetarium.org/tyson/read/1995/11/01/the-tidal-force) which are responsible for Tidal Locking and should shed some light on what we can expect as side effects.

> When the Moon flexes Earth's oceans, they simply slosh back and forth.
>   But **when a Jupiter-sized tidal force acts upon a nearby solid body,
>   then the internal stress can become a prodigious source of heat.** In
>   one of the more timely and impressive predictions in the history of
>   space probes, Stanton Peale of the University of California and
>   collaborators published a paper in 1979 titled, [Melting of Io by Tidal
>   Dissipation](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/49cf/72fc28e4bdab61efb05b8c43a31e867def6e.pdf). **Later that year, images sent by the Voyager 1 space craft
>   revealed extraordinary volcanic activity, complete with mountain
>   calderas and plumes.**

The two quick and dirty rules for figuring out how much heat your moon will receive are:

1. Closer the moon is to the planet -> MORE HEAT
2. Smaller the moon, the more the gas giant will affect the moon via gravity -> MORE HEAT

(As you can see by comparison, a moon the size of earth would be quite large)
[image: is a]]